# Why won't The Stanley Parable launch from Steam?

Tags: steam, the-stanley-parable-2011

So I decided to download The Stanley Parable after seeing it mentioned in an old review video I was watching.  I downloaded the zip, extracted it to the `steam/steamapps/sourcemods` folder, restarted Steam so it would show up, and when I click "play", nothing happens.  Literally nothing.  There are no new processes starting and getting hung up, I don't get any indication that clicking the button does anything.

Is there a way I can get it to work, or am I just out of luck?

Comment: Just for the record: A) Do any other Source games start properly? B) Can you check your online status upon clicking play? Does it manage to turn from blue to green at some point?

Comment: Do you have the Source SDK(s) installed?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, try installing both the source SDK and the source SDK base 2007. That worked for me.